# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ"

Tags: java, swing, parsing, encoding, locale

I have one field in Database ( Sql Server DB 2000) with varchar field in which i have stored Thai Sentence (in the form of Unicode ).I am using the Locale object to convert the unicode data into Thai sentence as follows

```
NumberFormat thai = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("th", "TH", "TH"));//Line1
String thaiText = ResultSet.getString(i);// Data Fetched From DB//Line2
double number = thai.parse(thaiText).doubleValue();//Line3
String outputString= nf.format(number);//Line4
```

I am getting the following exception on line no 3 :-

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ"
```

Comment: What is the value of thaiText after execution on Line 2

Comment: Following is the value ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ

Comment: @Prog_Anila there isn't any issue, depends of DB settting to the Thai and Java project to sets to the UTF-8, most important is type of DB engine, you didn't mentioned that, part of them support UTF-8 output, rest didn't, your question is simple un_answerable, add rest of important infos to your question,

Comment: @mKorbel i have modified question and we are using the UTF-8 encoding for netbeans and as far as db is concerned, in our one application (Delphi) we are displaying and storing the thai text correctly.

Comment: @Prog_Anila please read my [question about the same issue](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset), ther no changes betweens MsSQL2000 and 2005/8 for Charset and Collations

Comment: @mKorbel but this article doesnot address how to convert unicode into  UTF-8

Comment: not, if is correctly to set Chaset and Collation on MS SQL server then JDBC returns correctl Unicode or UTF-8, any another conversion(s) in the Java isn't required,

Comment: @mKorbel but even after setting my DB field to nvarchar as mentioned in the article same exception is coming

Comment: Can you tell how i correctly set the Charset and collation in sql server 2000 as this article doesnot addresses the issue

Comment: @mKorbel  I  changed my Collation to latin1_general_ci_as  and then to latin1_Thai_ci_as  buut same excption is comming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in line 3; i.e. it is not with the way you are parsing the string.

The contents of `thaiText` has been corrupted due to an earlier problem with encodings.  You need to track down where the text is going bad.

- The text could be bad before you put it into the database.
- The text could be going bad when you put it into the database.
- The text could be going bad when you retrieve it from the database.

Figure out which of the above is the case, and that will tell you where you need to fix the problem.

Comment: We are using one software in Delphi in which Thai Characters are being displayed and stored correctly. It means the stored data is alright. But the problem is that while retreiving data in Netbeans it is corrupted.

Comment: Is there any way to read the unicode data from DB as bits and then print those in the collection of 16 bits sequence. and then convert those 16 bits to  thaiText(shown in above code) character by character.

Comment: no replies from your side even after i answered your question. @Stephen C

Comment: I didn't ask a question.  I suggested a course of action.  To answer **your** question, no I don't think so.  (Or at least, not without some risk that the JDBC driver etcetera will transform the text somehow.)  But if you are sure that the data is correctly in the database in a known Unicode format (and you can *absolutely prove* this by other means!!!) then you need to look at the way that you have configured the JDBC connection.  Specifically, you need to make sure that it is configured to decode the text based on the encoding actually used in the database.

Comment: Can you please tell how i configure my JDBC(which is JTDS in actual) and how i decode the text based on the encoding defined in Database. will be really thankful to you if you help me in this regard. @Stephen C

Comment: No I couldn't.  I'd have to track down and read the documentation, and figure out what is relevant to your setup.  It is better if you do that yourself.  It is your problem, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the data you are parsing is in wrong encoding.

You need to find out what is the data, you can use "Character set converter tool", for example like this one : http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php , find out what is the encoding for "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ"

then use following code to set the correct encoding.

```
    String original = "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ";
    String thaiText = new String(original.getBytes(charset1), charset2);//you need to work out charset1 and charset2 here by youself
```

Comment: this tool is converting as Ã¤Â¢Ã¨Â»Ã…Ã’Ã‹Ã…Ã¨Ã

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that the String you are reading from the database is not being decoded correctly.  You have indicated this in your comments.  You could try reading the comments out and FORCING the encoding.  This example is UTF-8:

```
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new
     ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes(i)), "UTF-8");

  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  char[] cbuf = new char[4096];
  int len;
  while((len=isr.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)) != -1) {
    sw.write(cbuf, 0, len);
  }
  isr.close();
  sw.close();

  String data = sw.toString();
```

Check that "data" has the correct information, then decode that into a number (if that makes sense) as you are already doing.

Comment: Do i replace my thai text(in line 2) with data given in your code?

Comment: Now with your code it is generating ????? marks on my line 2 when i repace thaitext with your  data variable